# Error starting clickhouse in Docker container

Tags: docker, clickhouse, docker-container

Today, I restarted the clickhouse service, but it couldn't get up. I went to check the logs and reported any errors, as shown in the following figure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR0rT.png)

Baidu hasn't found a solution for a long time. Can someone understand how to handle this problem？Thank you

I want to know how to solve this problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Did you try to run clickhouse inside WSL2 or WSL1 or do you use Docker desktop?

Answer (score 0):

it is not really clear to me what went wrong (looks like there are some leftovers). Perhaps you could try to start the Docker container with volumes mounted to different directories? See here: https://hub.docker.com/r/clickhouse/clickhouse-server/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly, but from the error it looks like the filesystem error is suggesting it tried to remove this directory but there is something still in the directory. May want to check that directory, or perhaps move it aside to allow the image to start:

/bitnami/clickhouse/data/store/bb9/bb99a*/delete_tmp_202308_623_623_0_bak/